# How to override invoice pdf file in magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2.2.0

I want to override **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php** and **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php** to show custom attribute in Invoice Pdf In magento2.2.0.
Any help would be Appreciated.